# How to detect "Use MFC" in preprocessor

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-2008

For a static Win32 library, how can I detect that any of the "Use MFC" options is set?

i.e.

```
#ifdef ---BuildingForMFC---
....
#else
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have always checked for the symbol _MFC_VER being defined.

This is the version number of MFC being used 0x0700 = 7.0

It is in the "Predefined Macros" in MSDN

Answer (score 5):

I've check on Visual Studio 2013, in an original project targeting only Win32 console, so I've to add MFC support (without using of the Project Wizard) in a second time. Following are my findings:

- The macro _MFC_VER is defined in the afxver_.h, included by afx.h. So, if you don't include afx.h directly/indirectly in your .cpp file, you don't have the _MFC_VER macro defined. For example, including in a project a source .cpp that doesn't include the afx.h, the file will be compiled *WITHOUT* the definition of _MFC_VER macro. So it's useless for adapt the c++ code (an external library, for example) to detect usage of MFC library and optionally support the MFC library.
- If you manually turn on the use of MFC (Select the project in Solution Explorer, than right click, Configuration Properties -> General -> Use of MFC) you have two possibilities:

  - A) select "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" option. This actually update the command line parameters adding the definition of _AFXDLL to the preprocessor macro list.
  - B) select "Use MFC in a Static Library" options. This actually remove the _AFXDLL macro defined, but no macro definition is added, so nothing can told you if MFC is actually used.

So, during my test activity, only the mode A can be used effectively to understand if the MFC library is included or not in the project under building.

I maintain a C++ cross-platform library that support many platforms (Mac OSx, WinX console, WinX MFC, iOS, Unix, Android) and enabling MFC with dynamic DLL is the only way to transparently detect the MFC presence. So for example:

```
#if defined(_AFXDLL)
#    include <afx.h>
#endif
```

Obviusly, you can add manually a macro definition (_AFX) in the project preprocessor list.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `_AFX` is typically defined for MFC projects.

Comment: I thought so muhc, too, but when enabling "Use MFC in a dynamic library" for a Win32 Library project (that was created without 'MFC support' option), this macro is not defined.

Comment: As @peterchen said, _AFX is not defined if MFC as dynamic library option is active, but _AFXDLL instead.